# How do I use a DataGridView in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

I am trying to build an employee data entry form that looks like this:

```
Employee Form
-----------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------       |
|           |  Name       |           |       |
|  Picture  |  Department |           |       |
|           |  Position   |           |       |
|           |  DOB        |           |       |
---------------------------------------       |
... repeat for every employee                 |
...                                           |
---------------------------------------       |
|           |  Name       |           |       |
|  Picture  |  Department |           |       |
|           |  Position   |           |       |
|           |  DOB        |           |       |
---------------------------------------       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

It's very easy to build this with Microsoft Access, but how can I build it using Winforms + C# + .NET 3.5?
I tried to use `DataGridView`, but I could not make it look like my example above.

Comment: Sad face in the extreme. i can't answer your question right now but i've created exactly what your talking about using VB.net and it shouldn't be that different. When i get home to my laptop I'll get on here and paste my code in and try to post a picture of that it looks like once ran. The only thing im not sure about is i think i might have used a listView instead of a DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I'm finally home with my laptop. So what i did to do the same thing your wanting to do is i used a ListView that i fill in dynamically from a datatable. Here is the code (summary of what i'm doing with is as at the bottom after code):

```
 For i = 0 To frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim tmpGroup As ListViewGroup = New ListViewGroup(frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("MechName"))
            ltvMechs.Groups.Add(tmpGroup)
            Dim tmpListItem1 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(tmpGroup)
            Dim tmpListItem2 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(tmpGroup)
            Dim tmpListItem3 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(tmpGroup)
            Dim tmpListItem4 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(tmpGroup)
            Dim tmpListItem5 As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(tmpGroup)

            'row1
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co1")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co2")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co3")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co4")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co5")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co6")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems.Add("co7")

            tmpListItem1.SubItems(0).Text = "Select"
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(1).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("Price")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(2).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("MechID")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(3).Text = "Faction Orientation"
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(4).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("FactionOrientation")
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(5).Text = "Engine HDP"
            tmpListItem1.SubItems(6).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("EngineHardPoint")


            'row2
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co1")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co2")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co3")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co4")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co5")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co6")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems.Add("co7")

            tmpListItem2.SubItems(0).Text = ""
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(1).Text = ""
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(2).Text = ""
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(3).Text = "Required Rep"
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(4).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("RequiredRep")
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(5).Text = "Generator HDP"
            tmpListItem2.SubItems(6).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("GeneratorHardPoint")


            'row3
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co1")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co2")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co3")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co4")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co5")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co6")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems.Add("co7")

            tmpListItem3.SubItems(0).Text = ""
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(1).Text = ""
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(2).Text = ""
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(3).Text = "Resilience"
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(4).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("Resilience")
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(5).Text = "Heavy HDP"
            tmpListItem3.SubItems(6).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("HeavyHardPoint")


            'row4
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co1")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co2")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co3")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co4")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co5")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co6")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems.Add("co7")

            tmpListItem4.SubItems(0).Text = ""
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(1).Text = ""
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(2).Text = ""
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(3).Text = "Weight"
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(4).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("Weight")
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(5).Text = "Medium HDP"
            tmpListItem4.SubItems(6).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("MediumHardPoint")


            'row5
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co1")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co2")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co3")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co4")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co5")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co6")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems.Add("co7")

            tmpListItem5.SubItems(0).Text = ""
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(1).Text = ""
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(2).Text = ""
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(3).Text = "Structure"
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(4).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("Class")
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(5).Text = "Light HDP"
            tmpListItem5.SubItems(6).Text = frmSelection.MechDataTable2.Rows(i).Item("LightHardPoint")


            ltvMechs.Items.Add(tmpListItem1)
            ltvMechs.Items.Add(tmpListItem2)
            ltvMechs.Items.Add(tmpListItem3)
            ltvMechs.Items.Add(tmpListItem4)
            ltvMechs.Items.Add(tmpListItem5)
        Next
```

Basically, each list item is a row in the group, each subitem is a cell in the row (similar to what you would see in excel, access ect.) subitem(0) is in col1, subitem(1) is in col2 ect. For your first column you will have subitem(0) of listItem1 be the picture and all of the other subitem(0)'s you will want to make blank. As i said im my comment above, i coded this in vb.net but by all accounts i've seen it isn't that much different than C#. Also here is a picture of part of what this code produces. sorry for the quality but it's the best i could do with what i had to work with. [alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7977/listviewexample.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7977/listviewexample.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try building a custom control which contains all the data for a single employee then adding multiple instances of that control to a FlowLayoutPanel or something similar. Your custom control could be simple with just a split panel containing a PictureBox and some TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

First, get [BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/). Then, rather than using DataTables/Sets, you can bind List<T>s to DataGridViews. You can then set the DataPropertyName of the second column to a "Details" property like this:

```
public string Details 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}", Name, Department, Position, DOB); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try binding your data to a Repeater like so?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">
                <%# Eval("Picture") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Department") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Position") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("DOB") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Great for WebForms. Not so useful for WinForms.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0 which comes with DataRepeater. 

I am stuck with how to enumerate the elements inside the repeater. Why can't Microsoft provide easy access to the DataRepeater children?